# Reset Kafka streams applications via code / api

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm Wunderding what would be the best method to perform this kind of operation with Kafka Streams.

I have one Kafka stream and one KGlobalTable let's say products (1.000.000 msg) and categoriesLogicBlobTable (10 msg).
Every time a new message arrives at the topic categoriesLogicBlobTable I need to reprocess all the products applying the new arrived message to products and the output goes to a third topic.

I was thinking on using the kafka.tools.StreamsResetter logic and hooking on my code in a way that I stop the kafkaStream run the reset and start the stream again.

A Second alternative is to not have kafka streams but only two consumers  and one producer. This way I could use the method consumer.seekToBeginning(Collections.emptyList());

Answer (score 0):

Resetting a KafkaStreams application would result in a lot of duplicate output for this case. Assume you have 10 records in the stream and 5 records in the table and while processing you produce 3 output record. Now, you add a 6th record to the table, and re-read the full stream. Thus, you would re-emit the first 3 output record to the output topic, and maybe additional output records if some records also join to the newly added 6th table record. This does not seem like what you want.

I guess you need to use KafkaConsumer/KafkaProducer manually.